# help to write a query statement

Tags: sql, join

I need a query statement written such that it searches three tables

**table 1**

```
id
fullname
active
```

**table 2**

```
id   
fullname
```

**table 3**

```
id 
fullname
```

I wanted this query to search all three tables combine and give me the result for those id 
fullname that is not active

Comment: Not very clear. Joins the 3 tables, and filter by `active=0`? Searching `JOIN` in SO should give hundreds of examples...

Comment: Can you add some sample data and sample output?

Comment: Join on what field?? What condition (equality)?? Or do you want a UNION across all three tables... we need more info...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all tables have the same structure (in your example they do not - is this an error?) then you can use UNION ALL to combine results from multiple queries:

```
SELECT id, fullname, 'table1' AS source
FROM table1
WHERE active = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, fullname, 'table2' AS source
FROM table2
WHERE active = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT id, fullname, 'table3' AS source
FROM table3
WHERE active = 'N'
```

If you don't care where the rows come from you and you don't want duplicates you could try UNION instead:

```
SELECT id, fullname
FROM table1
WHERE active = 'N'
UNION
SELECT id, fullname
FROM table2
WHERE active = 'N'
UNION
SELECT id, fullname
FROM table3
WHERE active = 'N'
```

I'm making a lot of guesses here. If it doesn't work, please clarify what you are trying to do.